# How do you update an SSE (Server Sent Event) message with POST request

Tags: php, server-sent-events

Please excuse me, I am quite new with backend development.

What I try to accomplish is pretty straight forward. I want to send a POST request to my server. As an example; [www.domain.com/api.php?id=foo](http://www.domain.com/api.php?id=foo)

And with that value update my SSE with that parameter. But I can't seem to figure it out. I guess I need to store that value somehow in a database or a text file? Preferably in a text file for simplicity.

What I have now:

**HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>

        <script>
            if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP file:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$test = "One";
echo "data: Page: {$test}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

**So my question is:** How do I change the value of the variable 'test' from a POST request so that the SSE is updated?

It works perfectly now, if I change the value in the PHP file it starts spitting that out in the HTML. But how do I change that value with something external like a POST call?

Thank you! And let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to make it work with a SQL database. :) This is my solution:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

// QUERY THE DATABASE FOR CURRENT PAGE NUMBER
$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database_name); // connect to the DB
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT number FROM page WHERE itemId=1"); // prepate a query
$query->execute(); // actually perform the query
$result = $query->get_result(); // retrieve the result so it can be used inside PHP
$r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // bind the data from the first result row to $r

// ECHO SERVER SENT EVENT
$pageNumber = $r['number'];
echo "data: Page: {$pageNumber}\n\n";
flush();

// UPDATE QUERY BASED ON GET PARAMATERS
$siteURL = $_GET['page'];
$updateQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE `page` SET `number` = '$siteURL' WHERE `page`.`itemId` = 1;");
$updateQuery->execute();

?>
```